# XSLT using JDeveloper Checking for conditions in source

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsd, jdeveloper

I'm trying to map two XSD's in J Developer to generate a transformation(XSLT).

**My Problem**

In my `source XSD` i want to check for a `condition` lets say if `idNumberType =10` then i have to `map PAN Number(in source XSD) to InIdNum(In Target XSD)`. If `idNumberType =4` then i have to `map Passport number(in source XSD) to InIdNum(In Target XSD)` etc.

Any suggestions/comments/edits will be welcoming.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a basic conditional processing using [`xsl:choose`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl%3achoose). The following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="person">
      <person>
         <InIdNum>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="idNumberType='10'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="panNumber"/>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="idNumberType='4'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="passportNumber"/>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:text>???</xsl:text>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </InIdNum>
      </person>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input xml

```
<xml>
   <person>
      <idNumberType>10</idNumberType>
      <panNumber>Pan1234</panNumber>
      <passportNumber>Pass1234</passportNumber>
   </person>
   <person>
      <idNumberType>4</idNumberType>
      <panNumber>Pan9876</panNumber>
      <passportNumber>Pass9876</passportNumber>
   </person>
   <person>
      <idNumberType>53</idNumberType>
      <panNumber>Pan53</panNumber>
      <passportNumber>Pass53</passportNumber>
   </person>
</xml>
```

Results in this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
   <person><InIdNum>Pan1234</InIdNum></person>
   <person><InIdNum>Pass9876</InIdNum></person>
   <person><InIdNum>???</InIdNum></person>
</xml>
```

Replace the identity template with whatever you need to do with the rest of the document.